# Is it possible to make longer output length with keras?

Tags: keras, forecasting, recurrent-neural-network

I want to predict some index related to space weather(kp, Dst,etc..) with RNN or LSTM. It was possible to build many to one model although it shows poor accuracy. However, my goal is to predict 7 days in the future with last 3 days observation.

The question is, is it functionally possible to build RNN which has longer output length(or timestep?) than input?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can. One way of doing it is using the so called "sequence to sequence" architecture. It enables you to input a sequence of data points and predict a sequence of values. It works by encoding the input with a fixed size vector (usually the last hidden state of an LSTM) and then using it as starting state for another LSTM that is unrolled for n time steps.
If you have labels for all the 7 steps you want to predict then you can use a model as the following one where the decoder takes as input the labels as input for each time step 0 <= t < n:

```
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_encoder_tokens))
encoder = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_decoder_tokens))
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs,
                                     initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
```

As you can see the first LSTM encode the sequence with len `num_encoder_token` and we only keep its last state `[encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]]` and use it as initialization for the second LSTM (`decoder_lstm`) that is then fed with the labels and try to predict the label vector right shifted of 1.

For example if you have as input sequence day1, day2, day3 and you want to predict day4, day5, ..., day10, then you will feed the encoder with day1 to day3 and use day4 ... day9 as input for the decoder. The decoder label then will be day5 ... day10.

You can read more about this kind of model at https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I have some time to try your answer. I'll let you know my progress as soon as possible!